# Android - playing sound for a condition match inside a loop

Tags: android, audio

I want to play a sound file when a correct letter is pressed of a word to be guessed(in Android). Following is the code :

```
boolean letterMatch = false;
for(int k = 0; k < currentWord.length(); k++) {
  if(currentWord.charAt(k)==letterChar){
    letterMatch = true;
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.correct);                                               
    mp.start();
    correctLetters++;
 }}
```

The problem I am encountering is that it plays the sound for only some first set of letters that match but does not play the sound for other matched letters in the same word. Please suggest possible fix...

Comment: stop sound before first one is completed

Comment: call prepare listner and finish mediaplayer every time before starting a new request

Answer (score 0):

MediaPlayer is not the best solution here.  A better solution is to use a [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html). You load your sounds into it when the activity is created, then you can trigger them to play immediately at right time in your app.

Answer (score 0):

give it a try.

```
  boolean letterMatch = false;
for(int k = 0; k < currentWord.length(); k++) {
if(currentWord.charAt(k)==letterChar){
letterMatch = true;
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.correct); 
mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mp.setLooping(true);                                              
mp.start();
correctLetters++;
```

}}

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in my scenario :-( . The sound does n't even get played with this piece of code.